# Confusion with Spring MVC Form Handling and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a login form which will render a new page if the user exist in the database but i want to call ajax if the login is incorrect and update just the current page in the `<div id="errorlogin">`

```
<body>
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="auth" action="checklogin">
    <label>login</label>
    <form:input path="login" type="text"/>
    <label>password</label>
    <form:input path="pwd" type="password"/>
    <input  type="submit"/>

</form:form>

<div id="errorlogin"></div>
</body>
```

the first part is okey if the user exist

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/checklogin")
    public String printWelcome(@ModelAttribute("auth") Auth auth ) {

    List<Auth> listlogin = authDao.findByProperty("login", auth.getLogin(), "pwd", auth.getPwd());
    System.out.println("size : "+listlogin.size());

    if(listlogin.size() == 1)
        return "hello";     

    return "hello";
}
```

now how i can use ajax if the user doesn't exist and update just the current page ?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i update my question you can take a look ;)

Comment: You need to do an AJAX form submit and then catch the return value to decide whether to load a new page or keep the current page and update the div content. Your current code hits the controller via a page load - this needs to handled by JavaScript... Google it.